# Memory error when running Elasticsearch on Docker (macOS Monterey 12.3)

Tags: macos, memory, docker

The Docker container shuts down with error code 137 when running Elasticsearch.

This is the info from the logs:
`max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]`

I have tried to add `kern.maxfiles` to `sysctl.conf` and other solutions from the internet, which work with Linux and Windows. No luck with macOS.

macOS Monterey 12.3
ElasticSearch 7.17.6
Docker 20.10.17

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What solutions from the Internet have you tried that didn't work? You may want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445846/elasticsearch-max-virtual-memory-areas-vm-max-map-count-65530-is-too-low-inc.

Answer (score 2):

The `vm.max_map_count` sysctl value needs to be set on the virtual machine (VM) on which your containers run.

The following instructions are for Rancher Desktop. If you are using Docker for Mac or Docker Desktop, follow the instructions at this URL instead:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/docker.html#_macos_with_docker_for_mac

Software versions I used in this solution:

- macOS Monterey 12.6
- Rancher Desktop 1.6.0 using the **dockerd** container engine (find this under Preferences, Container Engine)
- Elasticsearch image `docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.4.3`

To temporarily try the new setting to determine whether it fixes the problem, run the following command in your terminal, but note that the setting will revert to its default when you restart Rancher Desktop (`sysctl -a` will show all current settings):

```
rdctl shell sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

To set this in a way that persists across Rancher Desktop VM restarts, I had to create this file (added `\` to escape the space character for shell copy/paste) …
`~/Library/Application\ Support/rancher-desktop/lima/_config/override.yaml`
… with this content:

```yaml
provision:
  - mode: system
    script: |
      #!/bin/sh
      set -o xtrace
      sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

The `set` line isn't required. It just provides extra output reflecting the commands being run, which could be useful in debugging the VM startup.

If your `override.yaml` already exists, you would need to merge the above YAML snippet into the file: if a top-level `provision` key already exists, then copy the `mode` line onward and paste it under the existing `provision` line, making sure to preserve the indentation; else, paste the whole snippet at the end of the file, putting `provision` at the start of a new line.

Documentation for `override.yaml`:
https://docs.rancherdesktop.io/how-to-guides/provisioning-scripts

The Lima VM source code has additional details on the override mechanism, in the *GLOBAL DEFAULTS AND OVERRIDES* section of the comments:
https://github.com/lima-vm/lima/blob/master/examples/default.yaml#L363

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed helpful answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not in MacOS
I was using [Rancher Desktop](https://rancherdesktop.io). After switching to [Docker Desktop](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/) everything is working fine

Thank you